# In a textarea, change the direction of the current line from "rtl" to "ltr"

Tags: jquery, css

I have a textarea with direction from right to left

```
#myTextarea
{
    direction: rtl; 
}
```

on an event, with jquery, i change the direction from left to right :

```
$('#myTextarea').css('direction', 'ltr');
```

this move the whole content of the textarea from right to left.

I want to move only the current line, and let the previous lines in their default direction.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: This is not possible, the text direction can only apply to the entire `textarea` element, not the lines within it.

Comment: These days requirements seem a bit crazy... Just this morning someone asked how to disable up/keydown on a focused select element

Comment: Yeah, i'm working on a mathematic website in arabic, and i want the user to be able to write in arabic (rtl), then write mathematic formula (tlr)

Comment: @Anas did you find any way to do this? I need same thing.

Comment: @CodeLover Unfortunately not.

Comment: I think for math formulas, you should go with any rich text editor i.e. TinyMCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, the text direction can only apply to the entire `textarea` element, not the lines within it.

Comment: This answer needs an update as it's common practice right now to set direction on each input line. Try it on twitter, or FB.

Comment: Feel free to add one. Although I would be surprised if Twitter of FB are using the standard `textarea` control, and not something they've created themselves to achieve this, so the original answer is still likely to be true.

Answer (score 1):

You can try inserting `'\u202E'` characters at the beginning of the line, which will change the direction.

Also note that this is more of a hack than a real solution, it might not work in all browsers and on all platforms, I would try to think hard about if this is really what I want. Maybe you would be better off with a rich text editor.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NrHBF/)

Comment: Can you make this work for the following? Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41987499/textarea-ltr-rtl